# What material should I use to make this element

Tags: construction, materials

[image]
How make this in a space of 7.5m length x 2.5m breadth?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. You're going to have to give us a whole lot more information before we can answer (e.g. which "element"? why? what are you making?) And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Actually it is to be made on terce taking things in mind that it is to made outside so what kind of material should i use

Comment: First you call an architect, who knows a SE, who knows the AHD, one of which whom can recommend a company that will make you a parts kit for a half a foot thick structure with custom curves, having calculated all load bearing requirements such as wind, snow, and otherwise structurally. This isn't 'DiY', it's *who do I call*.

Answer (score 1):

Looks rather reinforced concrete or ferrocement oriented, plus steel and glass. Naturally you'll need engineering, real life being somewhat different than modeling.

Answer (score 0):

I like wood, (glue laminated beams), except the use calls for some good reverberations.

Wood absorbs sounds rather than reflects them....unless you covered the interior with plaster.

A metal roof would not be appropriate, because it would need insulation on the interior to protect it from condensation...which would defeat the acoustics you’re probably searching for...

Btw, I’d think there would be two “zones” (the apex of each curve) that would be especially intriguing to stand in because of the sound.

Side note: Are you going to orient the space in a North-South direction with the clerestory facing East?  That way the early morning light could penetrate deep into the space through the clerestory windows? I think it would be nice to see “the light” move across the ceiling of the upper arch. (Where can I go to see this when it’s completed?)